# r.maxent.lambdas command not recognized in GRASS after installing extension

Tags: grass-7.0, maxent

Running Grass 7.0.5 on a Windows 10 machine, I installed the 'r.maxent.lambdas' addon with the g.extension command:

> g.extension extension=r.maxent.lambdas
>   Downloading precompiled GRASS Addons ...
>   Updating addons metadata file...
>   Installation of  successfully finished

Then when I try to use the command I get:

> r.maxent.lambdas
>   'r.maxent.lambdas' is not recognized as an internal or
>   external command,
>   operable program or batch file.

I've had success installing and using other addons, but I am still very new to Grass. Is there a step I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

The installation fails on Windows because r.maxent.lambdas is a shell script and not a Python script. The options are

- rewrite it using Python (perhaps contact the author?)
- use a non-Windows operating system like Linux

Comment: You could install an emulator such as cygwin that will run a shell script.

Comment: Yes, there are a few options. Indeed I was referring to the fact that it does not install with g.extension which does not support shell scripts.